# Re-create openstack artifacts from previous command output?

Tags: openstack

Is there an easy way to convert Openstack show command outputs into openstack commands ?
The goal is to rebuild an openstack environment after a complete wipe.

(for example: openstack network show myNet > out.txt,
then somehow generate the Openstack CLI command with appropriate fields to re-create this same exact network, based on out.txt ?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write the output of the show commands as json formated string into a file, so you can easily read the information of the output with python-script to create and execute your desired commands.

To print the output of an openstack-command as json, add a `-f json` at the end of your command.

Example:

```
openstack server show cirros -f json
{
  "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL",
  "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "nova",
  "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "test-system",
  "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": "test-system",
  "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000001",
  "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": "Shutdown",
  "OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null,
  "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "stopped",
  "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2020-07-22T08:41:06.000000",
  "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null,
  "accessIPv4": "",
  "accessIPv6": "",
  "addresses": "test-network=192.168.62.207",
  "config_drive": "",
  "created": "2020-07-22T08:40:46Z",
  "flavor": "f1 (273a2179-ac85-4c54-a40a-2c0121b338ff)",
  "id": "6d302fcf-4de3-45a5-93c0-eb95650e5952",
  "image": "cirros (86dded1f-8e0f-4342-906e-8ff9fbd854e2)",
  "name": "cirros",
  "project_id": "cbba4b1f3cb4460ca63e8ddb87c9b5fb",
  "properties": "",
  "security_groups": "name='default'",
  "status": "SHUTOFF",
  "updated": "2020-08-17T13:26:55Z",
  "user_id": "b6505d6801e84fb98d77d2461f9719c2",
  "volumes_attached": ""
}
```